# Avoiding boilerplate with OptionT (natural transform?)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz, scala-cats

I have the following methods:

```
trait Tr[F[_]]{

    def getSet(): F[Set[String]]

    def checksum(): F[Long]

    def value(): F[String]

    def doRun(v: String, c: Long, s: Set[String]): F[Unit]
}
```

now I want to write the following for comprehension:

```
import cats._
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._

def fcmprhn[F[_]: Monad](F: Tr[F]): OptionT[F, Unit] =
  for {
    set <- OptionT {
      F.getSet() map { s =>
        if(s.nonEmpty) Some(s) else None
      }
    }
    checksum <- OptionT.liftF(F.checksum())
    v <- OptionT.liftF(F.value())
    _ <- OptionT.liftF(F.doRun(v, checksum, set))
    //can be lots of OptionT.liftF here
} yield ()
```

As you can see there is too much of `OptionT` boilerplate. Is there a way to avoid it?

I think I can make use of `F ~> OptionT[F, ?]`. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin 2) They do not, but they actually needed to perform effectfull computation later. Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to nest the "F only" portion of the for-comprehension within a single `liftF`:

```
def fcmprhn[F[_]: Monad](F: Tr[F]): OptionT[F, Unit] =
  for {
    set <- OptionT {
      F.getSet() map { s =>
        if(s.nonEmpty) Some(s) else None
      }
    }
    _ <- OptionT.liftF {
      for {
        checksum <- F.checksum()
        v <- F.value()
        _ <- F.doRun(v, checksum, set)
        // rest of F monad for-comprehension
      } yield ()
    }
  } yield ()
```

Comment: It makes sense, but... nested for-comprehension... Thanks anyway

Comment: Also, I think the first comprehension section could be more simply written: `set <- OptionT.liftF(F.getSet()) if (set.nonEmpty)` since `OptionT` has a `withFilter` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in "mtl-style" instead. mtl-style refers to mtl library in haskell but really it just means that instead of encoding effects as values (i.e. `OptionT[F, ?]`), we encode them as functions that take an abstract effect `F[_]` and give that `F` capabilities using type classes. That means instead of using `OptionT[F, Unit]` as our return type we can just use `F[Unit]` as our return type because `F` has to be able to handle errors.

This makes writing code like yours a small bit easier, but it's effect is amplified as you add monad transformers to the stack. Right now you only have to lift once, but what if you wanted a `StateT[OptionT[F, ?], S, Unit]` in the future. With mtl-style, all you need to do is add another type class constraint.

Here's what your code'd look like written in mtl-style:

```
def fcmprhn[F[_]](F: Tr[F])(implicit E: MonadError[F, Unit]): F[Unit] =
  for {
    set <- OptionT {
      F.getSet() flatMap { s =>
        if(s.nonEmpty) E.pure(s) else E.raiseError(())
      }
    }
    checksum <- F.checksum()
    v <- F.value()
    _ <- F.doRun(v, checksum, set)
} yield ()
```

And now when you run the program you can specify the `F[_]` to be something like what you had before `OptionT[F, ?]`:

```
fcmprhn[OptionT[F, ?]](OptionT.liftF(yourOriginalTr))
```

Comment: I do not quite understand why did you replace `Some`/`None` with pure`/`raiseError`. Can you expand it a bit?

Comment: I added some more explanation :)

Comment: I still have some misunderstanding about this approach. You specified implicit parameter `E: MonadError[F, Unit]`, but even in case of `cats.effect.IO` we have only `MonadError[IO, Throwble]`. But `OptionT` instances rely on the `F`'s instances... Can you please clarify this one?

Comment: @St.Antario `OptionT[F, A]` has a `MonadError` instance for `Unit`, so you can use that one :)